# How Navigation Controller works - IOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have been working on an IOS application. I got an doubt while working related to Navigation controller. Here is my question.  I am pushing all my views into navigation controller when I want a view should appear. I am setting every page its title like..

```
self.tiltle = @"View1"; // Something like that.
```

I guess the navigation controller is the same, and view I am loading will only vary, If I am right, why every time the same title is not loading for every page, (If I am not set title like above it comes empty for new view loaded). If I am wrong... Please point it out.

thanks for your valuable suggestion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you push a `UIViewController` to a `UINavigationController`, the navigation controller read's the `UIViewController`'s `self.title` or the `self.navigationItem.title` and displays that on it's navigation bar. If you want to set the same title for all the children view controllers then you have to set `self.title` on each one of them.

Comment: I am customizing back button with an image, So every view do I need to do the same thing in did load? Any way is there so that I can do in one place it reflects in all views?

Comment: The back button or the left button, the title, and the right button are all properties of each view controller. If you want a single place to declare the same things for all your navigation children then create a base `UIViewController` subclass and derive your view controllers from there